# Every convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ has a countable and dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume the space is Euclidean space. Why every convex set has a countable and dense subset? How about in metric space? Any ideas or references?

---

It is used in process of proving Debreu's Theorem in Microeconomics ("each continuous reference has a continuous utility representation"). The textbook ("Lecture Notes in Microeconomic Theory" by Ariel Rubinstein) omit the proof but I'm curious.

Comment: Any subset of a separable metric space is separable. You can find proofs on this site.

Comment: Oops, since $R^n$ is separable, every subset of $R^n$ should also be separable, right? It seems that I've asked a stupid question.. Thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is a separable metric space (that is, $X$ has a countable dense subset) and $E\subset X$ then $E$ has a countable dense subset.

This is simple enough that proving it is easier than trying to look it up. Say $x_1,\dots$ is a countable dense subset of $X$. Let $$S=\{(n,j)\in\Bbb N^2\,:\,E\cap B(x_n,1/j)\ne\emptyset\}.$$For every $(n,j)\in S$ let $$y_{n,j}\in E\cap B(x_n,1/j).$$Then $$D=\{y_{n,j}\,:\,(n,j)\in S\}$$is a countable subset of $E$. And $D$ is dense in $E$:

Suppose $x\in E$ and $j\in\Bbb N$. Since $(x_n)$ is dense in $X$, there exists $n$ so that $$x_n\in B(x,1/j).$$This implies that $x\in B(x_n,1/j)$. So $(n,j)\in S$, and $y_{n,j}\in B(x_n,1/j)$ implies that $$d(x,y_{n,j})<\frac2j.$$